# Website author, text and date collection using php

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to be able to upload articles to my webpage by submitting their URL. Inside my webpage i'm trying to extract the author's name, the text, and the date of upload of an article, by using the URL of that article inside a search field. Τhen by pressing the submit button i want to be able to get those data and save them into variables. Is there any possible way of doing that? Thank you

Comment: Probably. Most things are possible

Comment: @Strawberry i managed to get the article's image and title but i'm having a trouble getting the other details..

Comment: You have written your question as if you think we are all looking at your display right now. Don't you think, you should provide more information?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i'm sorry this is the first time i'm using stack overflow, i'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is getting details from meta tags on a page, you can use the `get_meta_tags()` function which will return an array of meta tags

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

echo $tags['author'];       // author name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // keywords
echo $tags['description'];  // description
?>
```

If you plan on getting this details from the data on the site and not meta tags, you might need to learn web crawling 
[This is a tutorial about that](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/How-to-create-a-web-crawler-using-PHP.php)

Comment: thank you for your answer. My concern is that developers can use different name for their tags when creating their website so using meta tags is not a "safe" option because there haven't got a static name that everyone uses, plus i'll be using different article's with different URL's soon. Thank you again!!.

Comment: no, those are standard meta tags, and no one uses any not in the standards, since search engine crawlers wont regard them, if you need for different URLs you can make a function and set the url as a parameter of the function.

Comment: @GeorgeSmith - IMHO this is **the** answer for you. It's now on you to write code which will "interprete" the tags as you need.

Comment: @olayemii Ok thank you very much, i really appreciate your help!